# main.handlebars #if loggedIn

Tags: javascript, mysql, handlebars.js

I have tested everything. My logout button should appear and disappear based on the user's logged in session. Can someone please test and help me figure out whats going wrong? IF you look at my repository please review code in feature/iflogout

link to repository: https://github.com/Brainybrian316/Sweet-Nostalgia

This is a small idea of what the handlebars looks like. its too much code to post here so please checkout the repository. Any tips or advice will do.

```js
     {{#if loggedIn}}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button id="logout" type="button" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Logout</button>
                        </li>
                        {{else}}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/signup">Signup</a>
                        </li>
                        {{/if}}
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Where do you set the value of `loggedIn`?

Comment: inside user routes

Comment: you have to look in the branch called feaeture/iflogout IF you look at my repository

Comment: I see that `req.session.loggedIn = true` is set in a POST request handler that returns a JSON response. Therefore, this looks like an API handler and that your login is handled asynchronously. If this is the case, and your views are rendered server-side, then your view isn't going to automatically update when the successful response is returned to the browser. Is this what you are expecting? Or are you expecting the logged-in status to change on the next full page (server-rendered) request?

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I found the solution. If i understand you correctly the solution is along the lines of what you are leaning toward

Comment: What I am trying to say is that it needs to be made more clear what you are trying to before a concrete solution can be proposed. One thing that is certain is that you will need to make your logged-in session state available to your views/templates by assigning it to an object that your views have access to. Next, you need to make it clear how your app handles authentication - full-HTTP vs. XHR request - and how your UI should update when a successful auth response is received.

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE RESOLVED....
In my home-routes.js when we would render the home page the file looked as such:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => { 
res.render('homepage');
```

I added

```
{loggedIn: req.session.loggedIn}
```

be place within the res.render()
which now looks like this:

```
//GET home page
router.get('/', (req, res) => { // anyone can access this page
    //  home.handlebars file
    res.render('homepage', {loggedIn: req.session.loggedIn});
```

Now the button will come and go :D
but I also had to change the dashboard route to this:

```
router.get('/', withAuth, (req, res) => { 
    // home.handlebars file
    res.render('dashboard', {loggedIn: true });
});
```